# bash script to iterate through folders

Tags: bash, shell

I have 5 folders in Test directory with name output001 to output005. Each output folders have files with filename *.cl_evt in it. I want to enter the each output folders and want to run the below command in bash shell script. How to iterate through each folder and run the below code through bash shell script ?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "sw00092413002xpcw3po_cl.evt 
sw00092413002xpcw3po_cl_bary4.evt 
sw00092413002sao.fits.gz" | barycorr ra=253.467570 dec=39.760169
```

Comment: There are no "folders".  A "folder" is an artifact of the gui.  When you're working in the shell, get used to thinking of them as "directories".  It's not just a matter of semantics.  Folders contain files, directories do not.  Directories contain names.  The failure to understand that distinction is one of the most wide-spread misconceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command seq (with a format) to generate the numbers in the name of your directories... Like that:

```
for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 1 5); do 
    cd output$i
    echo -e "sw00092413002xpcw3po_cl.evt 
    sw00092413002xpcw3po_cl_bary4.evt 
    sw00092413002sao.fits.gz" | barycorr ra=253.467570 dec=39.760169 
    cd ..
done
```

If you want to adjust the name of the data file in each of the sub-directories, you can write it this way:

```
for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 1 5); do 
    cd output$i
    f1=$(ls sw*pcw3po_cl.evt 2>/dev/null)
    if [ "$f1" == "" ] ; then
        echo "no data file in directory output$i"
        continue 
    else
        f2=${f1/pcw3po_cl.evt/pcw3po_cl_bary4.evt}
        f3=$(ls sw*sao.fits.gz)
        echo -e "$f1
        $f2 
        $f3" | barycorr ra=253.467570 dec=39.760169 
    fi
    cd ..
done
```

Break-down of the script:

the command :

```
seq -f "%03g" 1 5
```

generates the sequence:

```
001
002
003
004
005
```

Which means that the loop :

```
for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 1 5); do
```

will loop 5 times, with variable i successively taking the value 001, 002, 003, 004, 005

Inside each loop, we're running a few commands. (Let's analyse the first loop when **i** contains **001**) :

the fist line of the loop :

```
cd output$i
```

is equivalent to output001 (so we go to the directory output001).

The last line of the loop:

```
cd ..
```

goes up one level in the directory tree (i.e. it returns to the directory where you were at the beginning of the script).

The following command executes : **ls sw*pcw3po_cl.evt** inside the directory **output001** and puts the result in the variable f1 :

```
f1=$(ls sw*pcw3po_cl.evt)
```

The following command takes variable f1, substitutes the string **pcw3po_cl.evt** with **pcw3po_cl_bary4.evt** and puts the result in the variable f2 :

```
f2=${f1/pcw3po_cl.evt/pcw3po_cl_bary4.evt}
```

The following command executes : **ls sw*sao.fits.gz** inside the directory **output001** and puts the result in the variable f3 :

```
f3=$(ls sw*sao.fits.gz)
```

The following command :

```
echo -e "$f1 $f2 $f3" | barycorr ra=253.467570 dec=39.760169
```

prints out the values of the 3 variables f1 f2 and f3 (which hopefully contains the file of the directory whose name matches (successively) sw*pcw3po_cl.evt,   sw*pcw3po_cl_bary4.evt, and sw*sao.fits.gz

Then it "pipes" these values into your application named barycorr as standard input of this application (so barycorr can read these filenames and probably process the files).

Comment: But I have one issue. Can you please help me with this. I need to give first input the filenames sw*pcw3po_cl.evt, secondly the filename I want to save like sw*xpcw3po_cl_bary4.evt and third the path where sw*sao.fits.gz file is located. The * changes according to which folder I am in. How to write the script now to run this program inside the each folder.

Comment: The inputs are after echo -e in above code.

Comment: I'm trying to reply by editing the post above (because it lets me format the code)...

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I think something is missing after echo -e in edited answer. Actually  can we do alternatively like command  :`echo -e "sw00092413002xpcw3po_cl.evt 
    sw00092413002xpcw3po_cl_bary4.evt 
    sw00092413002sao.fits.gz" | barycorr ra=253.467570 dec=39.760169`. Running this in iteration by changing the `000924413002' only in loop i.e. from 2 to 5 other remains the same. If one number is not there like 3 missed then it throws error. Need to by pass this error too.

Comment: You're welcome.. And owp, sorry: there was a typo while I was trying to close the double quote of the echo -e .. that should be fied in the newly edited post..

Comment: I don't understand what kind of error you got (and I can't reproduce your exact case here), but I tried to better describe what it was supposed to do so, hopefully, you could make it work... I put again the new lines between $f1 $f2 and $f3 in case barrycor needs it to understand on which file it's supposed to work

Comment: Actually the the input in second variable is not in the directory. I need to give the name by myself so that the `barycorr` program save input in that filename.

Comment: Actually `barycorr` is a prgoram which prompts to ask the input. So, as a first input I need to give 'sw00092413002xpcw3po_cl.evt` this which is inside the directory say `output0001` and then prompts to ask in what file name you want to save so I gave 'sw00092413002xpcw3po_cl_bary4.evt` after that It prompts to ask another file which is in different directory not inside `output001` but  in some other directory with file name  `sw00092413002sao.fits.gz`. but its not the issue I can copy and keep in that folder.

Comment: Okay, so if you just want to generate value for the second line that is the same than the file you gave on the 1st line after sustituting the ending pcw3po_cl.evt with another ending: po_cl_bary4.evt, this is easy enough. I edited the snippet of code above to generate variable f2 by substituting the ending from variable f1. Hope it will work for you

Comment: Wow! Just Worked perfectly. Thank you very much. I want to ask one thing how can I skip the error message when the program throws  if the `barycorr` didn't find file in let's say folder `output002`  or folder itself during iteration? I am this asking as I have discontinuous directories too.

Comment: You can test if it found the file by testing on the content of the variable. If there is no file matching sw*pcw3po_cl.evt the variable f1 will be empty. We can display a message and or skip the processing of the file in that case, I'm updating the code to reflect this. (note also the mention 2>/dev/null' at the end of the command to set f1, so there won't be any error message if the file doesn't exist)

Comment: Wonderful ! Tons of thanks. How to make log file of this whole process ? before `cd ..` if i add `&>log` can make log file ?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you can add '>>../log' at the end of the command to append every result to the same log file (log file will be in the directory where your script started) or you can add '>log' at the end of your command so every directory keeps its own result inside itself a separate log file. i.e.: output001/log output002.log, etc...